# Symfony - not recognise js script in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I added this JS script to twig template:

```
<script>
var images = JSON.parse('[]');
</script>
```

but after compile the code changed to:

```
<script type="d7fe36345345345fc57a-">
var images = JSON.parse('[]');
</script>
```

Browser not do js code, I see error: `images is not defined`.
Why `type="d7fe36345345345fc57a-"` is added to script tag and how to avoid it?

Comment: I used Twig for quite a while now and have never come across something like this. Are you sure this is related to Twig? Is there anything else that could affect the code?

Comment: I agree with @MaximeW - this is not `twig` related. See [here](https://twigfiddle.com/taqu2s)

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason.
Cloudflare add this code to  tag.
The solution is o change setting on Cloudflare.